# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when trying to read data from cookies in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I have written few lines of code which reads data from the cookies stored in a text file and then write it on the web browser whenever required.

Block of code which i am using to store and write the cookies on a text file-

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class StoreCookieInfo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Java Programs and files\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Your username");
driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("Your password");
driver.findElement(By.name("persistent")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).submit();

File f = new File("browser.data");
try{
     f.delete();
     f.createNewFile();
     FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(f);
     BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(fos);

     for(Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies()) {
            bos.write((ck.getName()+";"+ck.getValue()+";"+ck.getDomain()
                    +";"+ck.getPath()+";"+ck.getExpiry()+";"+ck.isSecure()));
            bos.newLine();
     }
     bos.flush();
     bos.close();
     fos.close();
 }catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }

  }
 }
```

It is running fine and storing data on text file.
Block of code which i am using to read cookies from the text file-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LoadCookieInfo {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Java Programs and files\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    try{
         File f2 = new File("browser.data");
         FileReader fr = new FileReader(f2);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
         String line;
         while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
             StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line,";");
             while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
                 String name = str.nextToken();
                 String value = str.nextToken();
                 String domain = str.nextToken();
                 String path = str.nextToken();
                 System.out.println("1");
                 Date expiry = null;
                 String dt;
                 if(!(dt=str.nextToken()).equals("null")){
                     expiry = new Date(dt);
                 }
                 boolean isSecure = new Boolean(str.nextToken()).booleanValue();
                 Cookie ck = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure);
                 driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
                 System.out.println(name+value);
             }
         }
    }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
 }
}
```

When i am trying to run the second code i am getting the following exception on date -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.Selenium_Practice.LoadCookieInfo.main(LoadCookieInfo.java:39)
```

This is the first time i am trying to read data using cookies so i am not able to figure out what wrong i am doing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java to convert a string into a date object use SimpleDateFormat Class.It is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates.It allows you to start by choosing any user-defined patterns for date-time formatting

In the `browser.data` file the date is saved in format `Sat Oct 03 01:12:17 IST 2015`

So use a `SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")`

**E**----->Day name in week(`Sat`)

**MMM**----->Month (`Oct`)

**dd**------>Day in month(`03`)

**HH:mm:ss**---->Hours:minutes:seconds(`01:12:17`)

**Z**----->Time Zone(`IST`)

**yyyy**---->Year(`2015`)

```
Date expiry = null;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

                try {
                     String dt;
                     if(!(dt=str.nextToken()).equals("null")){
                    expiry = formatter.parse(dt);
                    System.out.println(expiry);
                    System.out.println(formatter.format(expiry));
                     }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I tested the above code it was working fine.I was able to add the cookie successfully after applying the above changes to LoadCookieInfo class

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you have any queries

Answer (score 0):

The exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is thrown because you are passing String as a parameter to the [Date constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29), that is deprecated and replaced by `DateFormat.parse(String s)`.

```
String dt;
  if(!(dt=str.nextToken()).equals("null")){
    expiry = new Date(dt);
  }
```

Try Using:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")");
Date date = formatter.parse(dt);
```

There seems to be issue with your if condition also. `(dt=str.nextToken())` will assign the value and give you `true` always, never equaling to `null`.

Let me know if it works with above solution.

Comment: Getting the same exception after making the code changes